# Android - do a Path comparison

Tags: android, path, gesture

In the Duolingo app, there's a feature where you can learn to draw letters and validate them afterwards, as in the picture below.
[image]

I was curious as to what Android feature can be behind such functionality.

Is it Path? Is it Gestures?

And how to compare the symbol traced by the user and the reference symbol in the app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not built in.  They wrote the actual algorithms to compare it (or found/bought a library that does so).  The base is probably a first difference algorithm treating the (x,y) points of the touches as a stream of data and looking for the first difference to see the change of the path and the inflection points in the curves.  But they would have had to write all that themselves.

(First difference is the discrete data version of a first derivative.  An inflection point is the point of maximal curvature of a curve.  In continuous data, it happens at a 0 in the first derivative, with the sign of the second derivative determining if its a maxima or minima.  In discrete data the first difference serves similar purposes, although an exact 0 isn't likely).

Comment: So... Apart from the comparison, what do you think they used to trace the symbols?

Comment: TO get the touch data?  An onTouchListener is sufficient.  It will send an event for the touch, and an event for each move of a few pixels.  Remember to look at the historical x and y values as well as the current, as Android combines multiple move events into one in some circumstances.